# Renaming an object on a virtual and all consequent overrides

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, for naming consistency I'd like to rename an object that I have in a parent virtual void. However, I'd like the renaming to apply to all the overrides I do to this method (which are hundreds of them).

Eg:

```
public virtual void Execute(String text)
{
    // code
}
```

Then everytime I override this method it is called like this:

```
public override void Execute(string text)
{
    //
}
```

What I basically want to do is by renaming the parent method `text` variable to `Message`, apply those changes to the `override void` method as well. I'm not sure if this is something possible with visual studio or any additional package.

Comment: Selecting the parameter and using the ```CTRL``` + ```R``` + ```R``` shortcut to might do the trick.

Comment: You are renaming a parameter, not an object, nor a method. You can solve it with search/replace (Ctrl-H).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are talking about? You talk about *renaming an object on a virtual* (I'm not sure about what that means). Then you say *renaming the parent method text variable to Message*. That looks like you want to rename a parameter name for a method (and all of its overrides). I don't think that VS supports that as a auto-refactor option. Either a global search or perhaps *Find all references* will help you. Consider using `message` rather than `Message` if you are talking about a parameter name

Comment: I think there's no package for this, because your want to edit the code itself. 
I advice you to follow imsmn's and Olivier's comments.
But before you start, make sure your code is versioned (e.g. [Git](https://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/)). This way you can roll back your changes if you make any mistake.

Comment: In adition to Flydog57 comment when he advices you to consider using `message` for your parameter rather than `Message`:  This is a [Naming Guideline for C# development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-parameters). Follow the guidelines and every good C# developer in the world will understand your code. In the page mentioned it says : *DO use camelCasing in parameter names*. So is advisable for you to follow :)